# Why does the destructor not get called on a templated pointer when called expicitly?

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

In my test case below I am puzzled as to why the destructor does not seem to be get called even though I am explicitly calling it. I noticed this only happens when the template type is a pointer.

Code (with memory leaks, but I tried to make the smallest example possible)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() { cout << "A Destructor"; }
};

template<typename Type>
class TemplateTest {
protected:
    Type* start;
    Type* end;
    Type* iter;
public:
    void Generate(unsigned int count) {
        start = new Type[count];
        end = start + count;
        iter = start;
    }
    void DestroyAll() {
        for(; start < end; ++start) {
            (*start).~Type();
        }
    }
    void Push(Type val) {
        *iter = val;
        iter++;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "Non-pointer test" << endl;
    TemplateTest<A> npt;
    npt.Generate(5);
    npt.DestroyAll();

    cout << "\nPointer test";
    TemplateTest<A*> pt;
    pt.Generate(5);
    pt.Push(new A());
    pt.DestroyAll();

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Non-pointer test
A DestructorA DestructorA DestructorA DestructorA Destructor
Pointer test
```

Running example: https://ideone.com/DB70tF

Comment: Why in the world are you explicitly calling the destructor?  For what purpose?

Comment: It is a smaller test case of a std::vector implementation

Comment: Unless you're using `placement-new`, calling the destructor explicitly like that is not recommended (and I would dare say, a bug).

Comment: I am calling placement new in the long form version of the code. I made the example smaller to focus on the issue of the destructor not being called

Answer (score 5):

The destructor *is* getting called. It's just not the destructor you're thinking  of. Basically, you have this:

```
int main() {
    using T = A*;
    T* arr = new T[1];
    arr[0]->~T();
}
```

But `T` is `A*`, so the destructor your calling is the *pointer* destructor - which is trivial - not your class's destructor. At no point does your `TemplateTest<A*> pt` object actually create any instances of `A` - only instances of `A*`.

Comment: I updated the test case to show that with an A* object, it would still not get called.

Comment: @judeclarke That edit makes my statement about you not creating instances of `A` false, but it doesn't change the rest of the answer. You're never calling `A`'s destructor... only `A*`'s destructor.

Comment: How can I call the A* destructor in the example above?

Comment: I am calling placement new in the long form version of the code (a std::vector implementation). I made the example smaller to focus on the issue of the destructor not being called

Comment: "How can I call the A* destructor in the example above?" You probably shouldn't if you're imitating a std::vector. That will not delete pointed to objects if you create a std::vector<my_type*> and push pointers to it and delete it. This is treading on how you manage ownership of memory, the STL offers things like std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr for cases like this.

If you INSIST on calling a dtor for a pointed to object (lets say you were writing judeclarke::owner_vector<T>), you'll need to specialize the template class on pointers and invoke "delete" as well. (careful of type** tho)

Comment: relativebit, you have a good point and exposed the real issue with what I was doing wrong. If you put that into an answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @judeclarke You *are* calling the A* destructor. It just doesn't so anything, pointer destructors are trivial.

Comment: The destructor of A* is not the same thing as the destructor of A.

Comment: @jude may I suggest reading up on the difference between pointers and values before rolling your own `std::vector`?  Indirection is a hard problem that requires mastery if you aren't going to stumble a lot over it.  Compile time code generation is another difficukt problem.  Doing both together when you have mastered neither is error prone.